# Is marriage rejection on the basis of caste a criminal offence?

Tags: india, marriage, indian-penal-code, indian-constitutional-law

I am a Brahmin and my girlfriend is Schedule caste, and my parents are denying our marriage because of caste. Will it be considered a criminal offence under Indian caste discrimination law, if any?

Comment: What are you asking is an offence? Your marriage or your parent's denials?

Comment: Does it matter (from a legal perspective) that your parents don't like your marriage?  Unless you're a minor, I wouldn't expect their approval to be necessary.

Comment: Are they forcibly preventing you from marrying, or just not happy about it?

Answer (score 9):

The applicable law of India is [The Scheduled Castes And the Scheduled Tribes (Prevention of Atrocities) Act, 1989](https://cjp.org.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/The-Scheduled-Castes-And-the-Scheduled-Tribes-Prevention-of-Atrocities-Act-1989-1.pdf) plus the [2015 amendment](https://cjp.org.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Atrocities-Amendment.pdf). There are various prohibited acts, the majority of which are already crimes, such as numerous kinds of assault, trespass, unlawful eviction, also including knowingly making obscene gestures at    a  woman  belonging to  a  Scheduled Caste or a Scheduled Tribe. It also includes social and economic boycotts, to some extent (as a means of preventing such a person from voting). Parents can freely refuse to sanction / support the marriage of whoever they chose, but they cannot forcibly interfere, for instance by kidnapping one of the participants.